# Kick out cash drawer from Firefox on Ubuntu through Epson TM88iv

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, printing, kiosk, epson

I'm working with a kiosk application, and need to kick out cash drawer #1 from an epson t88iv. I need to be able to do this without printing anything, and from firefox on the ubuntu platform.

Any clues? Cash drawer kicks out right now on every print (from print settings), but this is not desired.

Thanks a lot,
Mark

Comment: This is very, very specific to that piece of hardware. You need to add more information about how it is connected to the machine, and it would be very helpful if you could consult the documentation or customer support about how to trigger that event *in general*. If the nature of the required action (like a signal through the serial port or whatever) is clear, *then* people may be able to recommend a ways to do it in Firefox.

Comment: Have a look at OpenBravo (http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Projects/POS/FAQ)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Printer is connected via USB. I will consult my tech to see how to open the cash drawer in general without printing anything. Thanks -Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the t88iv is ESC/POS compatible you could read the reference for the protocol

- http://www.mscashdrawer.com/Tech_Information/m80pm.pdf

Ps. On the OpenBravo reference: here are the tech specs/supported devices:

- http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Projects/POS/Technical_Specifications

Answer (score 4):

Standard Linux command to open drawer of the TM-T88IV

USB printer: echo -e -n "\x1b\x70\x30\x40\x50" > /dev/usb/lp0

Network CUPS Printer: echo -e -n "\x1b\x70\x30\x40\x50" | lpr -o raw -P Epson-TM-Network